# C++ get SessionID of Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: c++, windows, sessionid, credential-providers

I am trying to obtain the SessionID of the remote desktop connection.

So we have made a credential provider for windows in C++, but we are trying to obtain the session id that can also be found in the

Event viewer > Application and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager > Operational

Is there a way to obtain this Session ID?

Comment: if you implement credential provider your dll is running inside `LogonUI.exe` process. it exec from `winlogon.exe` which run in target session. so all what you need call `ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &SessionId)`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! :D